# Kак сделать чтобы при изменении одного значения объекта менялось зависящее от него

Tags: javascript, объекты

Есть некоторый объект `Graph`. У него есть свойство `width` и зависящее от него `height`.
Как сделать, чтобы при изменении значения width вместе с ним менялось и height?

```
function Graph(width){
this.width=width
this.height=0.5*this.width
}
Graph.prototype.changeWidth=function(){
this.width*=2
}

let graph=new Graph(10)
graph.changeWidh()
console.log(graph)
//→Graph{width:20, height:5}
/*Должно быть: 
    Graph{width:20, height:10}*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function Graph(width){
  this.width = width;
  this.changeHeight();
}

Graph.prototype.changeHeight = function(){
    this.height = 0.5 * this.width;
}

Graph.prototype.changeWidth=function(){
    this.width *= 2;
    this.changeHeight();
}

let graph=new Graph(10);
console.log(graph);
graph.changeWidth();
console.log(graph)
```

Comment: Вообще учитывая то как автор использует эти изменения, то можно просто высоту тоже умножать на 2, чтобы не создавать новых методов

Comment: @EzioMercer это да)) хз что ему надо в итоге) пока что есть